# Boundfield as part of Hyperlinkfield in a code generated gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink, boundfield

Can someone please explain to me how I can include a boundfield (`Emp_ID`) to the HyperLinkField (`IDNumber`) in a code generated GridView using C#? So that the url string would be `'../Pages/Home.aspx?Emp_ID=(Emp_ID)'>(IDNumber)</a>`

Thanks

Snippet code below:

```
IDColumn.DataField = "Emp_ID";
IDColumn.HeaderText = "Emp_ID";
string[] id = new string[] { "Emp_ID" };
IDColumn.Visible = false;
grid.Columns.Add(IDColumn);

hyperlinkedColumn.DataTextField = "IDNumber";
hyperlinkedColumn.HeaderText = "ID No.";
hyperlinkedColumn.DataNavigateUrlFields = id;
hyperlinkedColumn.DataTextFormatString = "<a href='../Pages/Home.aspx?Emp_ID='>{0}</a>";
hyperlinkedColumn.Visible = true;
grid.DataKeyNames = id;
grid.Columns.Add(hyperlinkedColumn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is set the DataNavigateUrlFormatString instead of DataTextFormatString.

```
string[] id = new string[] { "Emp_ID" }; 

HyperLinkField hyperlinkedColumn = new HyperLinkField();
hyperlinkedColumn.DataTextField = "IDNumber";
hyperlinkedColumn.HeaderText = "ID No.";
hyperlinkedColumn.DataNavigateUrlFields = id;
hyperlinkedColumn.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "../Pages/Home.aspx?Emp_ID={0}";
hyperlinkedColumn.Visible = true;
```

Comment: WOW. It's that simple. I got confused with the methods. Thanks.

Comment: Another question about this, is it possible to store the "EMP_ID" in Session? And if yes, how is it done? Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You can store anything you want in the session state by using Session["Emp_ID"] = "whatever". Do you mean ViewState? If you want to store the Emp_ID in the viewstate so you can access it for each row, try adding datakeys to the gridview - grid.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Emp_ID" }

Comment: Ooops, sorry for the confusion. Suppose I want to store EMP_ID in a Session variable, instead of putting it in the querystring, how can this be achieved?